# In Excel Office 365, I do not have the "Encrypt with Password" option

Tags: microsoft-excel, encryption, passwords, office365

On Microsoft's website, it  provides the following instructions to password protect an Excel workbook:

```
Select File > Info.

Select the Protect Workbook box and choose Encrypt with Password.

Enter a password in the Password box, and then select OK.

Confirm the password in the Reenter Password box, and then select OK.
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/protect-an-excel-file-7359d4ae-7213-4ac2-b058-f75e9311b599

However, in my Office 365 version of excel, these are the only options I see:

[image: Protect Workbook Options]

How can I password protect this workbook?

---

Edit in response to the answer saying I should see a password option when hitting "Save As":

[image]

Then when selecting "More options..."

[image]

Comment: Is this a personal or corporate installation of Office?

Comment: There is a key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16\Common\Security` we need to know the value of `DisablePasswordUI` in order to help you

Comment: Thank you, this is through my corporate work computer. I can not find the HKCU file that you mentioned. Could you include how to get there starting from the C drive

Comment: It's a registry key;  Asked your IT Administrator what Office group polices they have set.  The reason the option is missing is that your IT Administrator has set a group policy to not allow it (more than likely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you found may be correct, but you are not
getting the full menu that I get, as you are missing the
"Encrypt with Password" option:

[image]

Try this alternative method:
In the Review pane, group Protect, you will find a
Protect Sheet button. This protects from change,
but does not encrypt the document.

Press the button to show this dialog where you may specify what
to protect and a password:

[image]

If this also does not work, ask your IT people
why they have blocked all the options.